# Can I convert character encodings in an SQL Server stored proc?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, unicode, character-encoding

Due to "legacy" reasons a lot of our data is stored encoded in standard `varchar` columns along with the encoding that is used.

I'm working on a bulk upload routine in which I'd like to pass an xml string to a stored procedure (from C#). The xml string would all be in unicode with each element having an attribute indicating the desired target encoding (e.g. Shift-JIS for Japanese).

Is there some built-in mechanism in SQL Server for doing this kind of conversion in Transact-SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the data as UNICODE. Store also the desired 'encoding' as another column. Return both the data (UNICODE) and the desired encoding in your application. Transform the Unicode data to the desired encoding in the presentation layer, where it belongs.

Comment: As I say it's a legacy system, I can't switch the storage of the data to unicode. This is the whole problem.

Comment: Then you cannot store the data with the proper encoding. Is simple as that.

Comment: Fair enough then, I thought that would probably be the case. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
CAST(field AS varchar) [COLLATE][1] your collision
```

Comment: How do I use this? I tried SELECT CAST('日本語' as varchar(50)) COLLATE 'Shift_JIS' but I get a syntax error

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this IF you simply extract the data from the XML using `NVARCHAR` as the destination datatype. If the Collation is specified properly on the column (and it kinda has to be in order for you to not already have data loss), then it should convert to the proper Code Page:

```sql
DECLARE @SourceXML XML = N'
<Test>
  <Row>
    <Something Collation="Hebrew_100_CI_AS">בליפ</Something>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <Something Collation="Japanese_XJIS_100_CI_AS">如抜範浪偃壅國</Something>
  </Row>
</Test>'; -- the @Collation attribute is not necessary; only there for visual indication

DECLARE @Test TABLE
(
  HebrewCollation VARCHAR(20) COLLATE Hebrew_100_CI_AS,
  Latin1Collation VARCHAR(20) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS,
  JapaneseCollation VARCHAR(20) COLLATE Japanese_XJIS_100_CI_AS
);

INSERT INTO @Test ([HebrewCollation], [Latin1Collation], [JapaneseCollation])
  SELECT tab.col.value('(./Something/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)'),
         tab.col.value('(./Something/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)'),
         tab.col.value('(./Something/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)')
  FROM   @SourceXML.nodes(N'/Test/Row') tab(col);

SELECT *,
       DATALENGTH([HebrewCollation]) AS [HebrewColumnBytes],
       DATALENGTH([JapaneseCollation]) AS [JapaneseColumnBytes]
FROM @Test;
```

Returns:

```
HebrewCollation  Latin1Collation  JapaneseCollation  HebrewColumnBytes  JapaneseColumnBytes
בליפ
                 ????             ????               4                   4
???????          ???????          如抜範浪偃壅國       7                  14
```

<sup>Result row 1 is on two lines due to a right-to-left vs left-to-right display issue caused by the werbeH ;-)</sup>

The "HebrewColumnBytes" value of 4 for Row 1 is correct as the **Hebrew_*** Collations use Code Page 1255 which is a Single-Byte Character Set. Likewise, the "JapaneseColumnBytes" value of 14 for Row 2 is correct as the **Japanese_*** Collations use Code Page 932 which is a Double-Byte Character Set.